# Python Image Identification package

Tags: python-3.x, image

What packages does Python have to analyze and classify image features, 
such as 1000 images, which can analyze images and classify them according to their characteristics?

Answer (score 0):

scikit-image is an open-source Python package that works with numpy arrays. It implements algorithms and utilities for use in research, education and industry applications 
Documentation: [Scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide.html?source=post_page---------------------------)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case:-

> **PIL** *(Python Imaging Library)*

PIL is the standard library for image processing in python.

**PROS:-**

- Easy to use, as compared to other libraries

**CONS:-**

- Slow as compared to other Image processing libraries (cv2, Scikit etc)
- Doesn't include support for machine learning, in image processing

> **OpenCV** *(Open Source Computer Vision)*

OpenCV  is a library for real time computer vision.

**PROS:-**

- Efficient Processing (due to numpy arrays)
- Supports Video Processing as well
- incorporates Machine Learning in processing
- A complete package for Image/Video processing (meaning is self sufficient)

**CONS:-**

- Requires at least a basic understanding of Image and video processing in order to begin with (not that beginner friendly as compared to PIL)

> SciKit Image

Scikit-image is a Python image processing package for SciPy.

**PROS:-**

- Written Totally in python, therefore well commented code
- Efficient Processing (due to numpy arrays)
- incorporates Machine Learning in processing

**CONS:-**

- Does not supports Video Processing as OpenCV (but that's not that much of a problem as Scikit Image is an image processing package only)

One thing that all the libraries have in common is that these libraries are Open Source, so improvements always happens over time.

Comment: Just a reminder `cv2` is the library name for OpenCV in python